# Why it's unresolved reference error for calling setBackgroundResource() on an ' id ' in Mainactivity.kt?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.colormyviews

import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setListeners()
    }


    private fun setListeners(){
        val boxOneText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_one_text)
        val boxTwoText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_two_text)
        val boxThreeText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_three_text)
        val boxFourText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_four_text)
        val boxFiveText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_five_text)

        val rootConstraintLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.info_text)

        val redButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.red_button)
        val greenButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.green_button)
        val yellowButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.yellow_button)

        val clickableViews: List<View> =
                listOf(
                        boxOneText, boxTwoText, boxThreeText,
                        boxFourText, boxFiveText, rootConstraintLayout,
                        redButton, greenButton, yellowButton
                )



        for (item in clickableViews){
            item.setOnClickListener{makeColored(it)}
        }


    }

    private fun makeColored(view: View){

        when (view.id) {

            // Boxes using Color class colors for the background
            R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
            R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)
            R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

            R.id.red_button -> box_three_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_red)
            R.id.yellow_button -> box_four_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_yellow)
            R.id.green_button -> box_five_text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_green)
            else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }


}
```

XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_one_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/box_one"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_two_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/box_two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_one_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_three_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_three"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_four_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/box_two_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_four_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_four"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/box_five_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_three_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/box_five_text"
        style="@style/whiteBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_wide"
        android:text="@string/box_five"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_four_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/how_to_play"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/info_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/tap_the_boxes_and_buttons"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/label_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/box_two_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_red"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/yellow_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/yellow_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_yellow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/green_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/red_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/green_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="@string/button_green"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/yellow_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/yellow_button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In makeColored() function, while calling setBackgroundResource() on box_three_text, box_four_text, box_five_text. It throws me an ' Unresolved reference error '. However id's with same name has been declared in XML file. I can't understand where the problem lies, Please help me to understand what's going on and why it is unable to read id's in Mainactivity.kt which has been declared in Mainactivity.xm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of id use reference

```
 R.id.red_button -> boxThreeText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_red)
 R.id.yellow_button -> boxFourText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_yellow)
 R.id.green_button -> boxFiveText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_green)
```

and make these buttons global variable. You can directly use ids if you are using kotlin synthetic, however I can't see any such import in your code. (And anyway you should not be using be kotlin synthetic as Kotlin-extension plugin is deprecated)

Comment: Yep stored all id's view in variables and performed operation on variables itself. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id you have to define global variable, like this :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private  lateinit var boxOneText: View
  private lateinit var boxTwoText: View
  private lateinit var boxThreeText: View
  private lateinit var boxFourText: View
  private lateinit var boxFiveText: View

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setListeners()
    }

    private fun makeColored(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
            R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
            R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)
            R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

            R.id.red_button -> boxThreeText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_red)
            R.id.yellow_button -> boxFourText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_yellow)
            R.id.green_button -> boxFiveText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_green)
            else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
        }
    }

    private fun setListeners() {
        boxOneText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_one_text)
        boxTwoText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_two_text)
        boxThreeText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_three_text)
        boxFourText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_four_text)
        boxFiveText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.box_five_text)

        val rootConstraintLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.constraint_layout)

        val redButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.red_button)
        val greenButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.green_button)
        val yellowButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.yellow_button)

        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(
                boxOneText, boxTwoText, boxThreeText,
                boxFourText, boxFiveText, rootConstraintLayout,
                redButton, greenButton, yellowButton
            )

        for (item in clickableViews) {
            item.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it) }
        }
    }
}
```